# Are there different solution how retrieve waypoints?

Tags: swift, firebase

```
  "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0" : {
    "waypoints" : {
      "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG1" : {
        "latitude" : 13.17078652595298,
        "longitude" : -59.5775944578738
      },
      "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG2" : {
        "latitude" : 13.15541190861343,
        "longitude" : -59.57619643155932
      },
      "-KHbCuQg9W_tebl1pU66" : {
        "latitude" : 13.148444967591,
        "longitude" : -59.5589266947333
      }
    },
  "subtitle" : "jamesrick",
  "title" : "Highway",
  "type" : "polyline"
},
```

I have this structure for lines in Firebase. How retrieve all data with also nested node waypoints?

```
ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { polylines in
  if let objects = polylines.children.allObjects as? [FDataSnapshot] {
    for object in objects {
      polylineDictionary =  object.values as? Dictionary<String, AnyObjects> {

        //  ? ? ?

      }
    }
  }
  })
```

Now I have access to title, subtitle, type but how obtain access to waypoints? When I use

```
`polylineDictionary["waypoints"] as? [String: [String:Double]]`
```

so this dictionaries are not ordered. Thanks for some advice.

Comment: When you observe with .Value you are essentially saying 'Firebase, give me everything in the ref node; all children, children children etc, and I don't care what order they're in and also continue to watch for any changes (add, change, remove) and if that even occurs, give me all the data again'. Is that what you want? Or do you want specific nodes and/or a specific order? Once you establish what you are actually after and how you want it ordered, crafting the code is more straightforward.

Comment: @Jay: the children of the snapshot are also ordered when you get `.Value` *as long as you iterate over them with the [`children` property](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html#//api/name/children)*. Once you convert the object to a dictionary, all ordering guarantees are lost, since dictionaries are inherently unordered. But the solution is indeed typically as you say: listen at the right level, so that you can tell Firebase how to order the children.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes! Great catch. Taking the snapshot contents and stuffing it into a dictionary can randomize the order for sure. It's not clear from the question if the ordering is important, I think the OP is asking how to access the individual waypoints from the snapshot? Is the order important?

Comment: Only OP can answer that. But given a number of recent questions on the exact same data structure, I think it will be. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would get the nested waypoints... it's basically by iterating through the keys... I would also add some error checking when grabbing the longitude and latitudes to make sure they're there, but this is the gist:

```
if let polylineDictionary["waypoints"] as? [String: [String:Double]] {
           let waypoints = Array(polylineDictionary.keys)


           for i in 0..<waypoints.count {
              let waypointId = waypoints[i]
              let latitude = polylineDictionary[waypointId]["latitude"]
              let longitutde = polylineDictionary[waypointId]["longitude"]
           }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question about ordering; if you just want to get to the waypoints, it's pretty straight forward:

Assume your complete Firebase structure is:

```
root_node
  "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0" : {
    "waypoints" : {
      "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG1" : {
        "latitude" : 13.17078652595298,
        "longitude" : -59.5775944578738
      },
      "-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG2" : {
        "latitude" : 13.15541190861343,
        "longitude" : -59.57619643155932
      },
      "-KHbCuQg9W_tebl1pU66" : {
        "latitude" : 13.148444967591,
        "longitude" : -59.5589266947333
      }
    },
  "subtitle" : "jamesrick",
  "title" : "Highway",
  "type" : "polyline"
  }
```

Suppose I want the data for this specific node, -KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0

```
let nodeRef = rootRef.childByAppendingPath("-KHbCuQflKHrJiUmfpG0")

nodeRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value , withBlock: { snapshot in

  print(snapshot.value) //prints everything in the node

  let title = snapshot.value["title"] as! String //to get any element
  print(title) //prints Highway

  var waypoints = [String: [String:String]]() //dict to hold key:value, unordered

  waypoints = snapshot.value["waypoints"] as! Dictionary
  print(waypoints) //prints the 3 waypoints and their children (as a dict)

  //get fancy and convert the dictionary to an array (which can be sorted)
  let arr = waypoints.map {"\($0) \($1)"}

  for point in arr {
      print(point)
  }
}
```